# Where does Delphi Store the Data Explorer Connection Info?

Tags: delphi, dataexplorer

I just created a brand new FireDAC InterBase connection called "MyNewIBConnection" in Delphi 10 Seattle. The connection works great.

Where does Delphi store this connection info?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy after you know where to look:
1. Click Tools > FireDAC Explorer
2. Click Connection definitions

The file location is displayed in the Workstation configuration panel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not Data Explorer but FireDAC Explorer. You've asked where does Data Explorer store the definitions, read your title *"Where does Delphi Store the Data Explorer Connection Info?"* Even the screenshot in your question is Data Explorer. FireDAC Explorer can store definitions to the file you found so as in the dbxconnections.ini.

Comment: It's the **FireDAC** section of the _Data Explorer_. Both the _Data Explorer_ and _FireDAC Explorer_ write to the same location. (At least on my machine)

Comment: Not quite true. FireDAC created fake driver in dbxdrivers.ini (that's what you call section) and from FireDAC Explorer stores connection definitions  for its own explorer as well as for Data Explorer in dbxconnections.ini. It stores entries in two different files.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle. On my machine the _dbxconnections.ini_ file has not been modified since 01/19/2016.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the **dbxconnections.ini** file. I found it in this location (it may differ for your Delphi version):

```
C:\Users\PUBLIC\Documents\RAD Studio\dbExpress\dbxconnections.ini
```

How did I find it? After searching **BLACKFISHSQLEMPLOYEECONNECTION** term in registry (it was the rarest name in my [**Data Explorer**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Data_Explorer), was not found in registry), I ran [**Process Monitor**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with [**Rename Connection**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Modifying_Connections_in_the_Data_Explorer) dialog opened and filtered there non-registry operations of the IDE process.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the connection file (FDConnectionDefs.ini) ist stored in this registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\FireDAC\ConnectionDefFile`

Normally it uses the environment variable "FDHOME" inside this registry key to define the actual directory where the file is stored.

Comment: On my machine it referenced $(ADHOME). When I open Tools > Options > Environment Options > Environment Variables  neither "FDHOME" or "ADHOME" are listed.

Comment: ADHome and FDHome are defined in batch files that set up the demos. They have nothing in common with the Data Explorer.